# ubuntu 20.04 で、古いNASに接続するには

Tags: ubuntu, smb

ubuntu 20.04 環境を構築したところ、自宅のNASにSMB(CIFS)でアクセスできなくなりました。正確には、ファイル一覧は表示されましたが、読み書きができません。このNASは古いものなので、SMB1プロトコルしか対応していないと思うので、ubuntu 20.04 のデフォルトでSMB1が無効化されたことが原因ではないかと思っています。

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Ja を見ると、`/etc/samba/smb.conf`を変更する対応策が書かれていますが、これは、Samba 4.11についてで、ubuntuのGUI環境のファイルマネージャの挙動を変更することはできないようでした。そもそもSambaは入れておらず、おそらくgvfsとかfuseでマウントされるのだと思うのですが、ubuntuのファイルマネージャでSMB1プロトコルを有効にして、Windowsファイル共有に接続する方法はあるでしょうか？

---

（追記：2020-05-11）
smb.confに`client min protocol`の定義を記述したところ、新規ファイルを保存して、ファイルマネージャの表示を更新すると、ファイルであるはずのアイコンがフォルダに化けて、開けなくなってしまいました。NAS内のすべてのファイルがフォルダとして表示されており、ファイルの属性を間違って認識している様子です。そのファイルをWindowsから読み書きはできました。NASは NETGEAR ReadyNAS Pro 2 という機種です。

---

（追記：2020-06-04）
@taichi-yanagiya さんの回答で解決しました。メディアからインストールした直後の Ubuntu 20.04 は、sambaの不具合のため、NAS上のファイルにアクセスできませんでしたが、`apt update` `apt upgrade`でパッケージを更新することで、不具合は解消されたようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /etc/samba/smb.confを変更する対応策が書かれていますが、これは、Samba 4.11についてで、ubuntuのGUI環境のファイルマネージャの挙動を変更することはできないようでした。

実際に試してみましたか？
ファイルマネージャー(nautilus) も /etc/samba/smb.conf を見るようです。
[(参考URL)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229929/cant-acces-nas-anymore-after-upgrading-to-20-04)

smb.conf の [global] セクションに `client min protocol = NT1` または `client min protocol = CORE` を設定してみてください。

---

(追記: 2020-05-12)

ファイルがフォルダに見える件、Fedora の事例ですが、Samba ライブラリのバグのようです。
[Red Hat Bugzilla - Bug 1801442](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1801442)
[The Samba-Bugzilla – Bug 14101](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14101)